# Mock swagger auto-generated api class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, swagger

I have some API clients auto-generated by Swagger, for the sake of simplicity let's say I have (these are auto-generated):

- ApiClient <-- This is the base client
- UserApi <-- This takes in `ApiClient` in it's constructor

Now I have created a `ApiUtils`:

```
public class ApiUtils {
    private UserApi userApi;

    public ApiUtils(final ApiClient apiClient) {
        userApi = new UserApi(apiClient);
    }

    // Methods here
}
```

I want to mock this class, and I was hoping that I could use `InjectMethod` for the `UserApi`. I tried the following:

```
public class ApiUtilsTest {
    @Mock
    private ApiClient apiClient;
    @Mock
    private UserApi userApi;

    @InjectMock
    private ApiUtils apiUtils;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       apiUtils = new ApiUtils(apiClient);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
       when(userApi.doSomething).thenReturn(myMock);
       apiUtils.someMethodThatUsesApiUser ...
    }
}
```

But because `UserApi` is initialized in the constructor of the Utils class, then my mock for it is not injected.

How can I mock this?

Comment: Could you add either an alternative constructor, or a setter for userApi to the ApiUtils class?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem if I do that, I'll only be adding it for testing purposes. I prefer not add a method that I wouldn't be using in real production.

Comment: If code is more testable, then it's more maintainable, which is a win-win.  You shouldn't be shy of adding artefacts that improve the testability of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a simple [library](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-rest-spring) which supports [mocking](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-rest-spring/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/skjolber/mockito/rest/spring/RestServiceRuleInterfaceTest.java) Swagger-generated stubs as service endpoints (on a local port) using Mockito.

The implementation flavour and code-generation settings will affect whether things will work, but at least this is a starting point. Feel free to file issues and/or PRs for supporting your use-case.